# How to pass template ref as props (Vue3)

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, ref, vue-props

I want to pass the template ref of a parent to the child. How can I achieve this?

Parent

```
<script>
const parentRef = ref()
</script>

<template>
  <div ref="parentRef">
    <Child :parentRef="parentRef" /> //How to pass as props here??
  </div>
</template>
```

Child

```
const { x, y, isScrolling, arrivedState, directions } = useScroll(parentRef) //want to pass the parent template ref here
```

Comment: You're doing it correctly, but for the purposes of `useScroll` (I assume from the VueUse lib) it's not going to work.  You need to rethink your strategy.  Why does the Child need to determine the scroll properties of the Parent?  Determine those values _in_ the parent itself and pass them to the Child.

Answer (score 0):

In Vue 3 props have a [one-way data flow](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#one-way-data-flow) (parent -> child).

One way to create a two way data flow between parent and child is to use [`provide`](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html#provide) and [`inject`](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html#inject).

In your parent you have to provide the value:

```js
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { ref, provide } from "vue";
import Child from "./Child.vue";

const parentRef = ref<HTMLElement>();

provide("parentRef", parentRef);
</script>

<template>
  <div ref="parentRef">
    <Child />
  </div>
</template>
```

You can then inject the value in your child component:

```js
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { inject, Ref } from "vue";
import { useScroll } from "@vueuse/core";

const parentRef = inject<Ref<HTMLElement>>("parentRef");

const { x, y, isScrolling, arrivedState, directions } = useScroll(
  parentRef.value,
);
</script>
```

You can see a working demo using a counter in vanilla Vue 3 [here](https://play.vuejs.org/#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).